How to save type of an object
I have backend and frontend projects. I want to copy backend types to frontend.
On backend I have
const app = SomeFunctionThatGeneratesSomething();
export type App = typeof app;

I want to save App to file and use on frontend
import {App} from "savedBackendApp"


Note: This assumes you have some sort of monorepo where the backend and frontend are in the same codebase.
You can't really write a type to a file*. But you can just import a type made from an object.
Just import the type from your backend project directly.
// backend
const foo = { bar: string }
export type Foo = typeof foo

// front-end somewhere
import type { Foo } from '@my/backend/path/foo'

By using import type you ensure there there are no runtime imports, and your backend code stays on the backend, but you can use types declared in your backend code in the frontend.

* You could use the typescript package to read files and write out the type definitions according to your own logic. But that's going to complicated, and probably not the solution you really want.
